# How to create `df2` with four numerical variables using three cathegorical variables and one numerical variable from `df`

Tags: r, dplyr

I have next dataframe:

```
  df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(c("A"),8),rep(c("B"),8)),
                   Datetime=c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2020-08-05 17:00:00","2020-08-05 18:03:00","2020-08-05 22:54:00","2020-08-06 01:08:00","2020-08-06 13:26:00","2020-08-06 19:04:00","2020-08-08 11:00:00",
                              "2020-08-04 03:00:00","2020-08-04 15:00:00","2020-08-04 23:00:00","2020-08-06 14:00:00","2020-08-06 17:00:00","2020-08-06 20:00:00","2020-08-07 04:00:00","2020-08-07 16:00:00"),
                   Period=c("Day","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day"),
                   State=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),
                   Acc=c(1.1,2.3,1.7,1.4,0.1,1.9,2.9,2.3,1.1,0.1,1.4,0.2,2.6,1.3,1.7,1.0))
  
  df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")
  
  df

   ID            Datetime Period State Acc
1   A 2020-08-05 12:00:00    Day     1 1.1
2   A 2020-08-05 17:00:00    Day     2 2.3
3   A 2020-08-05 18:03:00    Day     1 1.7
4   A 2020-08-05 22:54:00  Night     1 1.4
5   A 2020-08-06 01:08:00  Night     1 0.1
6   A 2020-08-06 13:26:00    Day     1 1.9
7   A 2020-08-06 19:04:00  Night     2 2.9
8   A 2020-08-08 11:00:00    Day     2 2.3
9   B 2020-08-04 03:00:00  Night     1 1.1
10  B 2020-08-04 15:00:00    Day     1 0.1
11  B 2020-08-04 23:00:00  Night     1 1.4
12  B 2020-08-06 14:00:00    Day     2 0.2
13  B 2020-08-06 17:00:00    Day     2 2.6
14  B 2020-08-06 20:00:00  Night     1 1.3
15  B 2020-08-07 04:00:00  Night     1 1.7
16  B 2020-08-07 16:00:00    Day     1 1.0
```

I need to estimate the mean value of `Acc` per `ID`, `day`, `Period` and `State`. I would need a dataframe like this:

```
  ID   Datetime State.1_day State.1_night State.2_day State.2_night
1  A 2020-08-04          NA            NA          NA            NA # This day there was no data for `A`, but there was for `B`.
2  A 2020-08-05         1.4           1.4         2.3            NA
.  .      .              .             .           .              .
.  .      .              .             .           .              .
.  .      .              .             .           .              .
```

Does anyone know how to get it? I don't know how to calculate the mean using all these variables at once and then create the columns I showed.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach using the tidyverse. If you want to show all days even if they are not present for some IDs then use the second approach.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# your data
df <- data.frame(ID=c(rep(c("A"),8),rep(c("B"),8)),
                 Datetime=c("2020-08-05 12:00:00","2020-08-05 17:00:00","2020-08-05 18:03:00","2020-08-05 22:54:00","2020-08-06 01:08:00","2020-08-06 13:26:00","2020-08-06 19:04:00","2020-08-08 11:00:00",
                            "2020-08-04 03:00:00","2020-08-04 15:00:00","2020-08-04 23:00:00","2020-08-06 14:00:00","2020-08-06 17:00:00","2020-08-06 20:00:00","2020-08-07 04:00:00","2020-08-07 16:00:00"),
                 Period=c("Day","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Night","Day","Day","Night","Night","Day"),
                 State=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,1),
                 Acc=c(1.1,2.3,1.7,1.4,0.1,1.9,2.9,2.3,1.1,0.1,1.4,0.2,2.6,1.3,1.7,1.0))

df$Datetime <- as.POSIXct(df$Datetime,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", tz="UTC")

# first approach
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Day = as.Date(Datetime), Period, State) %>% 
  summarise(Acc = mean(Acc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(State, Period),
              values_from = Acc,
              names_prefix = "State.")

#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID', 'Day', 'Period' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 6 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Day [6]
#>   ID    Day        State.1_Day State.2_Day State.1_Night State.2_Night
#>   <chr> <date>           <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#> 1 A     2020-08-05         1.4         2.3          1.4           NA  
#> 2 A     2020-08-06         1.9        NA            0.1            2.9
#> 3 A     2020-08-08        NA           2.3         NA             NA  
#> 4 B     2020-08-04         0.1        NA            1.25          NA  
#> 5 B     2020-08-06        NA           1.4          1.3           NA  
#> 6 B     2020-08-07         1          NA            1.7           NA

# second approach
df %>% 
  group_by(ID, Day = as.factor(as.Date(Datetime)), Period, State, .drop = FALSE) %>% 
  summarise(Acc = mean(Acc, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(State, Period),
              values_from = Acc,
              names_prefix = "State.") %>% 
 select(!State.NA_NA)

#> `summarise()` regrouping output by 'ID', 'Day', 'Period' (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 10 x 6
#> # Groups:   ID, Day [10]
#>    ID    Day        State.1_Day State.2_Day State.1_Night State.2_Night
#>    <chr> <fct>            <dbl>       <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
#>  1 A     2020-08-04        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  2 A     2020-08-05         1.4         2.3          1.4           NA  
#>  3 A     2020-08-06         1.9        NA            0.1            2.9
#>  4 A     2020-08-07        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  5 A     2020-08-08        NA           2.3         NA             NA  
#>  6 B     2020-08-04         0.1        NA            1.25          NA  
#>  7 B     2020-08-05        NA          NA           NA             NA  
#>  8 B     2020-08-06        NA           1.4          1.3           NA  
#>  9 B     2020-08-07         1          NA            1.7           NA  
#> 10 B     2020-08-08        NA          NA           NA             NA
```

<sup>Created on 2020-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks @TimTeaFan, Do you know how to include the same range of dates for `A` and `B`? I want to plot those values overtime for the different individuals, and it would be helpful if for all of them the dates are the same. In this example, I would need to have for each `ID` the dates between `2020-08-04` and `2020-08-08`. Is this possible?

Comment: Did you see my second approach? It should show all dates for each `ID`. I convert the date to a factor and then use the `.drop = FALSE` argument in `group_by`.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see it! It looks perfect now. Thanks for your time and this wonderful reply.

Comment: No problem, I updated right after my initial post ;)

Comment: Hi @TimTeaFan, I am now using the code you proposed. That is why I did not give you the green mark yet. However, I have found a problem. I get an error message when I use your second approach, it says 'Error in map_lgl(.x, .p, ...) : object 'State' not found'. Do you know why? I guess it has to be something silly, but I do not figure out what.

Comment: Ok, I solved the problems about the mentioned message. I did not have some packages updated and there was a problem with that. However, now I get a different problem. I get the following message error `Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `State.NA_NA` doesn't exist.` Is the use of `State.NA_NA` right? I have seen that no column has this name...

Comment: If you don't have that column then you can drop `select(!State.NA_NA)`. In the case if your example data, I get a `State.NA_NA` column because not each ID has each day and this is filled with `NA` when using `pivot_wider` after summarizing.